# Java Setting a placeholder or variable method

Tags: java, methods, simplify

I know that something like this is possible in Python and other languages, but I'm looking to see if there's something basic I'm overlooking in Java, or if the language just isn't set up to do this Basically I want to have an if/then or switch which is presently like the following:

```
if X {
fillRect(<bunch of variables>);
} else
drawRect(<bunch of variables>);
```

and instead I want to do the following, which would be possible in other languages, and imho is more elegant because  shouldn't need to be repeated for a simple choice

```
if X{
funct = fillRect;
} else funct=drawRect;
funct(<bunch of variables>);
```

is there no reasonably easy way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: You're probably looking for the `Consumer` interface.

Comment: Consumer only takes one variable, and they don't have a consumer for 4 variables by default, but I think I get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's absolutely possible in Java. You just need an interface that defines the 'functions' that can be assigned and, subsequently, called.

For example:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Operation { 
    int operate(int arg1, int arg2);
}

Operation operation;
if (X)
    operation = (a1, a2) -> a1 + a2;
else
    operation = (a1, a2) -> a1 - a2;
int result = operation.operate(1, 2);
```

I've used lambda functions to define the operations but they could just as easily be method references.

Java also comes with a host of standard interfaces in the `java.util.function` package of the `java.base` module so you generally don't even need to define an interface. The one in my example could be replaced with `BinaryOperator<Integer>`.

Comment: Is there a Generic functional interface for some reasonable number of operands? That way I could basically have: If (X) { operation = (a<Shape>,b<int>,c<int>) -> fillRect(a,b,c);}
It would be easier to code this way if there were a default generic interface that just acquired the typings of a,b,c from the method that operation is cloning, but then again having it be flexible like this does allow for some more specific cases.

Comment: @procersapientiae Some extra libraries, like Vavr, do have interfaces with arbitrary numbers of parameters (like `Function4(T, U, W, X)`), but by this point, it usually makes sense to just create your own interface with a sensible name.

Comment: @procersapientiae I suggest you define an interface. This will make future readers understand what you doing better than using a general purpose interface. With respect to 'acquir[ing] the typings of a,b,c from the method' - there are ways you can do this but keep in mind that Java is a strongly typed language. It is designed (for better and worse) to force the coder to think about the type of each variable. It's not the language to choose if you want loose or implied types.